# check the text to change the background color

Tags: jquery, select, text

I'm looking for a way to check if the user is putting the words in the correct order to change the background color. So here is my code that was made with a friend of mine:
It's first creating a phrase that is "I am not." that you can change by clicking on it (it uses a select).
You can now say "I am blue." so I'd like to make an event to check what is the sentence saying and to change the body background in order to fit the phrase.

I would also like to check if there is this order of words, in the middle of a sentence like, "it's raining, **I am blue** and wet"

```js
        
    
    $(document).ready(function() {

                });

                let phrases = ["I am not. "

                ];
                let lettres = /[\u0041-\u005a\u0061-\u007a\u00aa-\u00b5\u00ba-\u00c0\u00c1-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6]/gui;

                tokenize = function(phrase) {
                    let mots = [''];
                    let it = phrase[Symbol.iterator]();
                    for (var c = it.next(); !c.done; ) {

                        for (; !c.done && c.value.match(lettres); c = it.next()) {
                            mots[mots.length-1]+=(c.value);
                        }
                    //console.log(c.value);
                    if (mots[mots.length-1].length != 0 ){
                        mots.push('');
                    }

                    if (c.value == ' ') {
                        for (c = it.next(); !c.done && c.value == " "; c = it.next()) {continue;} continue;
                    } 
                        // console.log(i);
                        
                        console.log(mots);

                        if (!c.value.match(lettres)){
                            mots[mots.length-1]+=(c.value);
                        //console.log(c.value);
                        mots.push('');
                    }
                    c = it.next();
                }
                return mots.slice(0, mots.length-1);

                    if (phrase === "I am blue."){
                            $(body).css('background-color', 'blue');
                    }
            }



            $(document).ready(function() {
                let LARGEUR = $("#container .repeat").clone();
                let change=function(){
                    $(".width_tmp_option", this.parent).html($('option:selected', this).val());
                    $(this).width($(".width_tmp_select", this.parent).width());
                }
                $('#container').on("change",".un",change);


                let idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(phrases.length));
                let mots = tokenize(phrases[idx]);

                for( var i = 0 ; i < mots.length-1; i++){
                    $('#container .repeat:last-child').after(LARGEUR.clone());}
                    var i = 0;
                    console.log(mots.length);
                    $('#container .repeat').each(function(){
                        $('.un', this).val(mots[i]).each(change);
                        i++;

                    });

            // for ( var i in mots){
            //  let div = LARGEUR.clone();
            //  div.find('.un').val(mots[i]);
            //  console.log(i);
            //  div.find('.un').each(change);
                //div.css('display', 'inline');


        //  }
        // //   $('#container .repeat:first-child').css('display', 'none');

    });
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Lexicon";
    src: url("fontes/Lexicon.woff") format("woff");
}


body {
    width: 70vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: normal;
    font-family:'Lexicon';
    overflow: hidden;


}

.un{
    width: 2rem;
    margin: 0.2rem;
    font-family: 'Lexicon';
} 

option {
    background-color: none;
    font-family: 'Lexicon';
}

option:hover {
    background-color: green;

}

::selection {
    background-color: green;
}

.width_tmp_select{
    background-color: none;

}


.width_tmp_select{
    display : none;
    font-size: 2.5rem; 
    font-family: 'Lexicon';
} 

.un{
    font-size: 2.5rem; 

} 

#p1{
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: none;
} 

select {

}

/* For IE10 */
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;

}

.repeat {
    display: inline-block;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="print.css" media="print">

    <title>Les Vergers</title>

</head>
<body class="white">

    <div id="container">
        <div class="repeat">

            <select name="mots" class="un">
                <option value=""> </option>
                <option value=".">.</option>
                <option value="I">I</option>
                <option value="am">am</option>
                <option value="blue">blue</option>
                <option value="not">not</option>
                <option value="!">!</option>

            </select>
            <select class="width_tmp_select">
                <option class="width_tmp_option"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {

                });

                let phrases = ["I am not. "

                ];
                let lettres = /[\u0041-\u005a\u0061-\u007a\u00aa-\u00b5\u00ba-\u00c0\u00c1-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6]/gui;

                tokenize = function(phrase) {
                    let mots = [''];
                    let it = phrase[Symbol.iterator]();
                    for (var c = it.next(); !c.done; ) {

                        for (; !c.done && c.value.match(lettres); c = it.next()) {
                            mots[mots.length-1]+=(c.value);
                        }
                    //console.log(c.value);
                    if (mots[mots.length-1].length != 0 ){
                        mots.push('');
                    }

                    if (c.value == ' ') {
                        for (c = it.next(); !c.done && c.value == " "; c = it.next()) {continue;} continue;
                    } 
                        // console.log(i);
                        
                        console.log(mots);

                        if (!c.value.match(lettres)){
                            mots[mots.length-1]+=(c.value);
                        //console.log(c.value);
                        mots.push('');
                    }
                    c = it.next();
                }
                return mots.slice(0, mots.length-1);

                    if (phrase === "I am blue."){
                            $(body).css('background-color', 'blue');
                    }
            }



            $(document).ready(function() {
                let LARGEUR = $("#container .repeat").clone();
                let change=function(){
                    $(".width_tmp_option", this.parent).html($('option:selected', this).val());
                    $(this).width($(".width_tmp_select", this.parent).width());
                }
                $('#container').on("change",".un",change);


                let idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(phrases.length));
                let mots = tokenize(phrases[idx]);

                for( var i = 0 ; i < mots.length-1; i++){
                    $('#container .repeat:last-child').after(LARGEUR.clone());}
                    var i = 0;
                    console.log(mots.length);
                    $('#container .repeat').each(function(){
                        $('.un', this).val(mots[i]).each(change);
                        i++;

                    });

    });

</script>

</body>


</html>
```

I started doing this that way :

```
            if (phrase === "I am blue."){
                        $(body).css('background-color', 'blue');
                }
```

But I believe its not right since it's not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean like this:

```
const actionTypes = {
  bgColor: 0,
  bgImage: 1,
  rotate: 2
};
const actions = {
  blue: {type: actionTypes.bgColor, color:"blue"},
  red: {type: actionTypes.bgColor, color:"red"},
  yellow: {type: actionTypes.bgColor, color:"yellow"},
  orange: {type: actionTypes.bgColor, color:"orange"},
  green: {type: actionTypes.bgColor, color:"green"},
  flower: {type: actionTypes.bgImage, src:"https://arts2science.files.wordpress.com/2018/12/flowers_02_460.jpg?w=640"},
  raining: {type: actionTypes.bgImage, src:"https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/heavy-rain-shower-meadow-background-with-sparkle-bokeh-raining-nature_79161-580.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg"},

}; // and so on
const wordSeparators = [' ', '.']; // the separator characters in the string. like '(', ')', '{`, '}', ' ' (space) and so on...

function detectColor (text) {
  let str = text;
  for (const wordSeparator of wordSeparators)
    str = str.split(wordSeparator).join('&clr_sprtr;');
  words = str.split('&clr_sprtr;');
  for (let word of words)
    if (actions[word] !== undefined) return actions[word];
}

let str = "I am raining and it's hot outside";

const action = detectColor(str);

switch (action.type) {
  case actionTypes.bgColor:
    $(body).css('background-color', action.color);
  break;
  case actionTypes.bgImage:
    $(body).css('background-image', `url(${action.src})`);
  break;
  case actionTypes.rotate:
    // implement rotation
  break;
}
```

Comment: May be you can get all colors in a json file format from a website and write a small script to convert it to that 'actions' object. or you can read the colors from this link: https://jonasjacek.github.io/colors/.

Comment: If it's ok, please check my answer as your question's answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
let color = phrase.slice(phrase.lastIndexOf(' '), -1);
$(body).css('background-color', color);
```

and it just works for sentences that are like this:

1. the 'color' is the last word in the sentence
2. after 'color' there is a `'.'` character
3. before 'color' there is a `' '` character

examples:
`I'm blue.`
`I love red.`
`the color is purple.`

Comment: thanks for your reply, but actually I'd like this very modular to use it and let people have fun with the sentences. So it would be better if it could check if there is a certain phrase in the complete text. Like : "It's 12pm, *I am blue* and it's hot outside"

Answer (score 0):

In that case you have to put all the colors in an array like and search and find the color in the string using code below:

```
const colors = ["blue", "red", "green", "purple", "pink", "orange"]; // and so on
const wordSeparators = [' ', '.']; // the separator characters in the string. like '(', ')', '{`, '}', ' ' (space) and so on...

function detectColor (text) {
  let str = text;
  for (const wordSeparator of wordSeparators)
    str = str.split(wordSeparator).join('&clr_sprtr;');
  words = str.split('&clr_sprtr;');
  for (let word of words)
    if (colors.indexOf(word) !== -1) return word;
}
```

And you can use the function in your code:

```
let str = "I am blue and it's hot outside";
$(body).css('background-color', detectColor(str));
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help.
By extension, I'd like to create some other events that are not only the colors, like "It's raining" so the background changes to an image.
or "I'm rotated" so the screen starts a rotation.
That's why I wanted something very modular to simply create *if* for each sentence and create an event.
Do you have any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: Well, actually, not if they are in the JS, right?
This would detect if I have the specific words and execute the $(body).css(*change*)
The point is that the computer is not interpreting them from the user, they are just scripted in my page.
Tell me if I get this wrong.
like  if (phrase == "I am blue. //or wathever"){
                        $(body).css('background-color', 'blue' // or wathever);
                }

Comment: So you can create several arrays. for example one for colors, other one for changing background image and so on.
for example if the word was 'raining', then change the background image to a raining image and if it was a color, change the color of bg and if it was 'rotate' something rotates in the screen...

Comment: that's it yes! But it seems very unclear to me...
What should an array look like in that case? I don't really see where to put this in my code...